# Calculate time elapsed for each category in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need help for a project of equipment follow-up.

I have a SQL table with 3 columns (Equipment Name, Status, Date of Status Change (DATETIME format)).

| EQUIPMENT | STATUS | CHANGEDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EQUIPMENT-1 | QUALIFICATION | 2020-06-30 09:37:42 |
| EQUIPMENT-1 | WAIT REPAIR | 2020-06-30 16:29:20 |
| EQUIPMENT-1 | UP | 2020-07-27 14:19:33 |
| EQUIPMENT-1 | ENGINEERING | 2020-09-18 15:25:01 |
| EQUIPMENT-1 | UP | 2020-09-20 17:31:53 |

The idea is to determine the elapsed time of each equipment in each status between 2 fixed dates.

For example, I would like to know the elpased time of EQUIPMENT-1 in all the status between the **2020-07-01** and the **2020-10-01** with a table result something like this

| STATUS | ELAPSED TIME (in days) |
| --- | --- |
| WAIT REPAIR | 26,60 |
| UP | 63,31 *(10,27 + 53,05)* |
| ENGINEERING | 2,09 |

Today I have a C# code which calculates theses elapsed times, but it's slow...
So i would to know if it's easy to replace this process by a SQL query.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You can look into the DATEDIFF SQL function

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Sorry, I use SQL Server (2012)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want `lead()` and aggregation:

```
select equipment, status,
       sum(datediff(minute,
                    changedate,
                    coalesce(next_changedate, '2020-10-01')
                   ) / (24 * 60.0)
          ) as decimal_days
from (select t.*,
             lead(changedate) over (partition by equipment order by changedate)
      from t
      where changedate >= '2020-07-01' and changedate < '2020-10-01'
     ) t
group by equipment, status;
```

EDIT:

If you need the initial time as well:

```
select equipment, status,
       sum(datediff(minute,
                    (case when changedate < '2020-07-01' then '2020-07-01' else changeddate end),
                    coalesce(next_changedate, '2020-10-01')
                   ) / (24 * 60.0)
          ) as decimal_days
from (select t.*,
             lead(changedate) over (partition by equipment order by changedate) as next_changedate
      from t
     ) t
where changedate >= '2020-07-01' and changedate < '2020-10-01' or
      next_changedate >= '2020-07-01' and next_changedate < '2020-10-01' or
group by equipment, status;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it's almost that.It just miss the time between 2020-07-01 and 2020-07-27 (first line)

Comment: Thanks for the edit Gordon, I have just need to had "WHERE CHANGEDATE < '2020-10-01'" in the subselect to have the good final elpased time. Now it works :)